# Drawing rectangle in an image - Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, shapes

I need to draw a rectangle inside an image, then i want to set all the area that is out of the rectangle (that filled by the orange airBrush) to black and save the editing!

Here is my code:

```
%Draw rectangle
shapeInserter = vision.ShapeInserter;
rectangle = int32([100 100 800 800]);
J = step(shapeInserter, imageA , rectangle);
imshow(J);
```

[image]

I was just drawn the rectangle, without any idea to complete my work, any help ?

Image dimension is 1000x1000.

Comment: Try this: `set(axes,'Color',[0 0 0])`

Comment: not that !, it fill the rectangle ! also with adding numbers to x and y axies !

Comment: Why not adding the rectangle _after_ you filled everything in black?

Comment: I need the area that within the rect. to be as it's ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RickRoll = rgb2gray(imread('Rick-Roll3.png'));  % 800x800 image
I = zeros ([1000, 1000]);
I(101:100+800, 101:100+800) = RickRoll;
```

[image]

Comment: And if you didn't mean this, then you need to restate your question better.

Comment: i need the original image that is located within the rect. ,  not a white color !

Comment: same :/
This is the whole code, u can check it: imageA = imread('2','bmp'); %load image
fftA = fft2(imageA); %fft
fftAShifted = fftshift(fftA); %shifting

imshow(fftAShifted ); %Draw rect
r = rectangle('Position', [100, 100, 800, 800]);

I = zeros ([1000, 1000]);
I(100:100+800, 100:100+800) = r;
imagesc(I); colormap gray;

Comment: the `rectangle` function just draws a rectangle. If you want the contents from a subrange in the image, then simply copy that subrange over the same subrange in a zero image.

Comment: Rick Astley lol. +1. It would be even better if you linked to the source of the original image and to make this reproducible, upload the image onto Stack imgur and use the URL in the `imread` function.

Comment: Ooooh, I hadn't even realised you can read from a URL directly with `imread`. Thanks for the tip! :D

Comment: Yes it is :) one of those things I learned on here, even though it's stated in the documentation... Which I hardly read.